# Some questions about how to close a connection by server in http

Tags: http

I'm working on an api that transmits photo to server. For the performance, I chose to use streaming. However, I found some clients (e.g. curl) throw an reset by peer error when the server close the connection before the left data is read due to some internal error.

I wonder if I should close the connection as soon as the error happens or close after the left data being read.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your priorities are. By that I mean:

> If you want to prioritize error handling as clients receive responses faster you should close the connection as soon as the error happens.

> On the other hand if you want to ensure data integrity(you dont want any data loss) close after the data is sent.